# Why does python give an error message whenever I use "-=" in place of "+="?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's puzzling is that I can use the `+=` operator in place of the `-=` without issue at line 12.

Program:

```
message = input("Enter a Message: ")

new_message = ""

VOWELS = "aeiou"
print()
for letter in message:
    if letter.lower() not in VOWELS:
        new_message -= letter



print("A new string has been created:", new_message)
print("Your message without vowels is:", new_message)

input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\no vowels (from book).py", line 12, in <module>
    new_message -= letter
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'str' and 'str'
```

edit: If I sound ignorant, forgot to mention, I'm new to programming

Comment: It's puzzling that different operators do different things? Why?

Comment: can you explain what it means to subtract one string from another? The question is unclear because we don't know what you expect it to do

Comment: @RyanHaining String deconcatenation?

Comment: @valer I think the term is "string decapitation"

Comment: How different????? `+=` adds and `-=` subtracts, looks obvious to me. However, the error message is very clear. You're trying to subtract letters and `-=` doesn't support that. You have to do something else in order to achieve your desired result. If you want a new message without vowels, then when building your new string, only add in the letters that you need.

Comment: I know they preform different functions. The point was they seemed like the same group of operators: in my mind, -= was to += as - was to +. Therefore, it didn't make sense to me originally why one operator would work despite the latter not working.

Comment: @JohnK. in that case then it's just a matter of making sense. Most people can agree how `"abc" + "def"` should behave, but I can't think of an obvious or reasonable implementation of `"abc" - "def"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings support the `+` and `+=` operators, since for a pair of strings, addition can be interpreted as concatenation. They don't support `-` or `-=`, since there's no meaningful string operation to translate subtraction into.

If you were using a numeric type, both kinds of operators would usually be supported.

Strings also support some other operators: You can multiply a string by an integer to repeat it that many times. You can use the `%` operator to do the older, `printf` style of string formatting (with either a single non-tuple argument on the right, or a tuple of several arguments).

Comment: Ok, I understand now. So basically, you can add a letter to a word, but you can't subtract a letter from a word. Learned something new.

Comment: Well, there are ways to remove certain parts of a string, but no single way that maps well to subtraction, so you'll need to use methods. Try `str.strip`, or `str.replace`. Or use regular expressions (not really recommended if you're new to programming, regex can be a lot to learn).